# Knowledge Distillation loss with Tensorflow 2 + Keras

Tags: python, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I am trying to implement a very simple keras model that uses Knowledge Distillation [1] from another model.
Roughly, I need to replace the original loss `L(y_true, y_pred)` by `L(y_true, y_pred)+L(y_teacher_pred, y_pred)` where `y_teacher_pred` is the prediction of another model.

I've tried to do

```py
def create_student_model_with_distillation(teacher_model):

  inp = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(21,))

  model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
  model.add(inp)

  model.add(...) 
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1))

  teacher_pred = teacher_model(inp)

  def my_loss(y_true,y_pred):
      loss = tf.keras.losses.mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred)
      loss += tf.keras.losses.mean_squared_error(teacher_pred, y_pred)
      return loss

  model.compile(loss=my_loss, optimizer='adam')

  return model
```

However, when I try to call `fit` on my model, I am getting

```py
TypeError: An op outside of the function building code is being passed
a "Graph" tensor. It is possible to have Graph tensors
leak out of the function building context by including a
tf.init_scope in your function building code.
```

How can I solve this issue ?

Refs

[1] https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.02531

Comment: The problem is likely `teacher_pred = teacher_model(inp)`. Keras is trying to backpropagate gradients through your teacher model. You could generate the teacher model logits while you create the dataset instead of in the loss function.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this blogpost is answer to your question: [keras blog](https://keras.io/examples/vision/knowledge_distillation/)

But in short - you should use new TF2 API and call teacher's `predict` before the `tf.GradientTape()` block:

```
def train_step(self, data):
        # Unpack data
        x, y = data

        # Forward pass of teacher
        teacher_predictions = self.teacher(x, training=False)

        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            # Forward pass of student
            student_predictions = self.student(x, training=True)

            # Compute losses
            student_loss = self.student_loss_fn(y, student_predictions)
            distillation_loss = self.distillation_loss_fn(
                tf.nn.softmax(teacher_predictions / self.temperature, axis=1),
                tf.nn.softmax(student_predictions / self.temperature, axis=1),
            )
            loss = self.alpha * student_loss + (1 - self.alpha) * distillation_loss
```

Comment: Hey @Alex, I have implemented knowledge distillation like this with resnet50 as my teacher and mobilenetv2 as my student. But the distillation loss is always coming as 0. On further probing, I found that `student_predictions` are very very small in magnitude as compared to `teacher_predictions`. So I changed the `softmax` to `log_softmax` for student_predictions like `tf.nn.log_softmax(student_predictions / self.temperature, axis=1)` . Now the distillation loss becomes a positive constant value. Is this correct ?

Comment: Haven't faced such problem. But possibly u should use models of the same class. Like `mobilenet_v2_1.4_224` as teacher, and `mobilenet_v2_0.35_224` as student to make distillation effective. Different mobilenetv2 types here: https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications/blob/master/keras_applications/mobilenet_v2.py

Comment: Actually, the meta answer to your question: if distillation works and score is better than without distillation - it's fine. Otherwise it's wrong.